# Webservice class instance does not persist, unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, nullpointerexception, instance

I've been looking at this issue we are having with an iOS app and it's `webservice` class. It seems that the class gets `initialized` and `assigned` an instance, but when we try to trigger the class by starting a timer button, it seems the instance has been removed from memory. This is how we `initialize` (and try to get an instance from) the class.

```
+ (ReflexionsMetaWebService *)getInstance
{
    static ReflexionsMetaWebService *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[ReflexionsMetaWebService alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}
```

I've determined that the button that's calling the class is working as intended by cleaning the references as mentioned in other topics on this forum. Is there maybe a cleaner way to initialize and maintain our webservice class instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue for the issue. Apparently the class was still instantiated, but a string was wrongly cast during the process. Our inexperience with the error-message led us to think it has something to do with the instantiation.

Thanks you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assigning this instance to an object that gets released from the memory. I don't think you have problem with your webservice class, by the look of it. Put a log message to check your class reference and the assigned reference before the timer kicks in and see where the problem is.

Comment: What I'd like to add is that the same class is being used for the logging in from a different screen. The logging in works well, and requesting a single record from the following list (which also uses this class) works well too. For some reason the instance maintains there until that specific button click. I'll have a look at that specific line of code.